# Please look over my code and help me

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I need to use `$` sign in `var reg` and what is the meaning of this line. I am new to programming so please help.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myPopup2(elem, mg) {
            var reg = /^[0-9]+$/;
            //alert(reg);
            //exit();
            if (elem.value.length == 0)
            {
                alert(mg);
                elem.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (elem.value.match(reg))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("this is not a number");
                elem.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <input type="button" onClick="myPopup2(document.getElementById('name'), 'pleas enter a value')" value="POP2!">
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: This would be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ && look into regular expressions

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: `^` and `$` are start and end regex anchors.

Comment: Learn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Elliot I was under the impression that  Codereview doesn't accept "fix my code" requests, though?

Comment: it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

$ says the **End of Line**

just have a look here [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#/%5E%5B0-9%5D+%24/)

Answer (score 0):

`/^[0-9]+$/` :

`^` - matches only from the beginning of string

`$`   - matches exactly to the end of string

`[]`  - set of characters

`0-9` - 0123456789

`+`   - one or more occurrence of that which it follows

I highly recommend this site for anything to do with regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/